# I'm having a strange Shell problem that I can't understand

Tags: linux, shell, sh

Because of a specific requirement scenario, I wanted to write a Shell script to monitor the DNS used by my Linux host.
Here's how I wrote it:

```bash
#! /usr/bin/bash

NETWORKING_DNS=$(nmcli dev show |grep DNS|awk '{print $2}')
echo "Current DNS: "
echo "$NETWORKING_DNS"
```

No problems so far, it outputs something like this:

```bash
xxx@xxx ~:$ bash script.sh
Current DNS:
1.1.1.1
1.0.0.1
```

Because I have other information to output, I wanted it to display it on one line, so I changed it to the following:

```bash
echo "Current DNS: $NETWORKING_DNS"
```

But when I was executing this script, something strange happened and its output became like this:

```bash
xxx@xxx ~:$ bash script.sh
Current DNS: 1.1.1.1
1.0.0.1
```

Why??

I thought it would output like this:

```
Current DNS: 1.1.1.1 1.0.0.1
```

I don't know why this is happening.
I've tried a number of things, such as using the -n option:

```bash
echo -n "Current DNS: $NETWORKING_DNS"
```

Or

```bash
printf "Current DNS: %s" "$NETWORKING_DNS"
```

None of them achieve the result I want.

Can anyone tell me why this is? (It's an "unimportant" question, but I'm kind of curious.)

My linux host info:

```bash
xxx@xxx ~:$ cat /etc/os-release 
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.2 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=focal
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal

xxx@xxx ~:$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.0.17(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

```bash
echo -n "Current DNS: $NETWORKING_DNS"
```

or

```bash
echo -ne "Current DNS: $NETWORKING_DNS"
```

or

```bash
printf "Current DNS: %s" "$NETWORKING_DNS"
```

It doesn't works.

Comment: Your first version is already printing a line break between the two IP addresses, why wouldn't the second?

Comment: I would peek at the content of your variable on the hexadecimal level, i.e. `printf %s "$NETWORKING_DNS"|xxd -pu`

Comment: @user1934428 The DNS have changed, it isn't 1.1.1.1 and 1.0.0.1.
`31302e31302e36302e31360a31302e31302e33302e3732`

Comment: They have, and you have a newline inside the string. Actually, what I see in your hex string, is `10.10.60.16` then a line feed, and then 10.10.30.72`. So there are completely different addresses AND you have a  line feed in it. If you want to debug this, you should try to get a reproducible test case.

Comment: @user1934428 As stated in my question, I have this script that I want to use to log my DNS. so it does change all the time in this environment. The second thing is that the `\n` was not added by me, it is objectively present in $NETWORKING_DNS. : D

Comment: Fine, then my suggestions would be to first sanitze the output, so that you don't have a line feed. If you really need a single variable to hold both addresses, make it an array of length 2. Or make two variables out of it, each holding only an IP address. Furthermore, the question is tagged incorrectly: You tagged it as _sh_, but you seem to use _bash_. Tag with the shell you are going to use in your script.

Comment: @user1934428 In my first case I have written `#! /usr/bin/bash` , The tags is indeed wrong.

Comment: @milkbro : FYI, and not related to your question: In your case, the #! line is irrelevant/ignored, because you run your script explicitly with `bash script.sh`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the other answers, the root cause is that there is a newline inside your `NETWORKING_DNS`.

You set up the content of that variable by processing it with AWK (`print $2`). There are several options that influence the output of AWK. (You can read the documentation of AWK for the details.) But the summary is: AWK is doing the `print $2`-action for every record it gets from the pipe. AWK separates the output of each action by printing the OutputRecordSeparator (or `ORS`).

The `ORS` is by default a newline, but you can tweak it to something different, e.g. replace your line in your script with:

```
NETWORKING_DNS=$(nmcli dev show |grep DNS|awk -v ORS=" " '{print $2}')
```

to change the ORS to space.

How it works:

- the invocation of awk sets the ORS variable to space instead of the default newline using the `-v` option

Comment: Thank you guys! You solved my problem.But this has introduced a new problem:
In my first example, why does it only output 3 lines instead of 4?
[Here](https://img.tg/image/OKQ3pM) have a picture to explain.

Comment: @milkbro Cann you add more details? E.g. add the output of `nmcli dev show ` and `nmcli dev show |grep DNS` from your system. I would guess in the output of `nmcli dev show |grep DNS` is a line that has nothing in the second column.   
If you need an extra newline, you could use an additional `echo` statement (or use `printf` for more control).

Comment: Reading the documentation of nmcli, you could probably just use `NETWORKING_DNS=$(nmcli -e no -g IP4.DNS device show INTERFACE)` and use the name of your interface, e.g. for my system INTERFACE would be enp9s0.

That would print a "|" between the values but everything in one line.

Comment: Fischer OK,[Here](https://img.tg/image/OKlTgC) is the `nmcli dev show |grep DNS` result.Maybe you misunderstood me, I wasn't trying to output an extra line, I was wondering why the last line was a missing `\n`.

Comment: @milkbro You can use `#!/usr/bin/bash -x` to debug your script, maybe that gives you an insight on what is going on on your system. You can use `printf` to have a bit better control on the output of your script.

The first point is to understand if the unwanted newline comes from the `echo "$NETWORKING_DNS"` line (maybe add an `echo "-------"` after it).  Or if it is from some line after that (and then find that line and fix it).

Answer (score 1):

> why this is happening

Variable contains `1.1.1.1` followed by a newline character followed by `1.0.0.1`.

The newline character when printed starts a new line. Advances cursor position to the next empty line, optionally shifting terminal output one line up, depending on the terminal, and moves cursor position to column 0.

The variable *contains* a newline character, it will be printed when variable content is printed, no matter the method.

Tip: you can debug variables with `declare -p NETWORKING_DNS`. Unquoted variable expansions undergo word splitting (and filename expansion), which joins words split by spaces - so you might `echo $NETWORKING_DNS`. Research ASCII, shell quoting, word splitting expansion, filename expansion. Check your scripts with shellcheck. To replace newline with a space, you can use `tr '\n' ' '`  or `paste -sd ' '`, see `man tr` and `man paste`.

Comment: Shouldn't it be "replace newline with a space" and `tr '\n' ' '`?

Comment: Makes sense, but why then was the newline not printed in the first case, `echo "$NETWORKING_DNS"`? The variable was quoted, and assuming that it was assigned in the same way in both cases, the effect should be the same.

Comment: `why then was the newline not printed in the first case, echo "$NETWORKING_DNS"?` The output in the question shows it was - the second code snippet. I do not follow.

Comment: As @user19344 said, why didn't `echo` not print its newlines in the first example?
It's not that I'm missing a line break in my first example, it's that my actual run results in only three lines, which by all rights should be four.(2 (`echo`) + 1 `\n` ).

Comment: [Here](https://img.tg/image/OKQ3pM) hava a picture to explain.